Asymptotic behavior of Shalika germs near non-regular elements
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over a $p$-adic field $F$. Let $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus. Fix a special maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G(F)$ and for any closed subgroup $H\subset G(F)$ we use the standard normalization of the measure on $H$: namely the volume of $H\cap K$ is $1$.
Now for any $f\in C_c^\infty(G(F))$, $\gamma \in T(F)$ regular, we can define
$$O_\gamma(f):=\int_{G(F)/T(F)}f(g\gamma g^{-1})dg.$$
The famous Shalika germ expansion claims the existence of a family of functions $\{\Gamma_{\mathcal{O}}\}_{\mathcal{O}}$ indexed by the rational unipotent orbits, such that

for each $f$ there exists a neighborhood $U_f\subset T(F)$ of $1$ (depending on $f$), with
$$O_\gamma(f)=\sum_{\mathcal{O}}\Gamma_{\mathcal{O}}(\gamma)\cdot \mu_{\mathcal{O}}(f),\quad \gamma \in T(F)_{\mathrm{reg}}\cap U_f,$$
where $T(F)_{\mathrm{reg}}$ means the subset of regular elements,

and the germs of $\{\Gamma_{\mathcal{O}}\}_{\mathcal{O}}$ at $1$ is uniquely determined.
We write $D(\gamma)$ for the discriminant of $\gamma$, and $\overline{\Gamma}_{\mathcal{O}}(\gamma):=\Gamma_{\mathcal{O}}\cdot |D(\gamma)|^{1/2} $ the normalized germs. Then it is a famous theorem of Harish-Chandra that if we regard $\overline{\Gamma}_{\mathcal{O}}$ as a function on the whole $T(F)$ via extension by $0$, then is locally bounded on $T(F)$.
I have learnt several most classical examples, such as $\mathrm{GL}_2$, and germs for regular unipotent orbits (the formula of Shelstad and Langlands, obtained in the theory of transfer). But I did not see any big theorem for general cases.
My question: is it true that in general when $\gamma \rightarrow 1$, $\overline{\Gamma}_{\mathcal{O}}$ all have limits? The examples I leant so far do have limits. But it seems to be unreasonable that such a result could exist. If this is wrong, is there a classical counterexample? (There is also a parallel question for Lie algebras.)
Finally, a soft question: are there known general theorems beyond Harish-Chandra's above local boundedness result? For example, when the torus is elliptic, can we say more about the properties of the germs? (Harish-Chandra observed that the germ of the trivial unipotent orbit vanishes unless the torus is elliptic, but I wonder if there is any deeper general result related to the general elliptic case.)
Thanks in advance for any discussion, help and advice. (Sorry for experts: maybe this question is too naive since I am a complete beginner.)
